# Set a Grails Domain Class as "No-Insert Mode"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to use a complex query on my Grails application. Instead of using a complex `criteriaBuilder()`, I instead performed the following:

1. Created `View` on the database, say `ParentChildView`.
2. Mapped it into a domain class.
3. Use this `ParentChildView` domain class to perform a `.list()` operation.

I'm wondering if I can configure this domain class to something like *"select-only mode"* or *"no-insert-allowed mode"*?— you know, just to make sure an `Exception` will be thrown if some developer accidentally tries to insert to this domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question, you don't want insertion to happen or for sure updates as well.

Your action could be one from these.

- User meta-programming and make save method throw an exception for domain. e.g.

  ```
  User.metaClass.static.save = {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Object is not in a state to be save.")
    }
  ```
- You could use hooks if not sure about meta-programming as below.

  ```
  def beforeInsert() {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Object is not in a state to be save.")
  }

  def beforeUpdate() {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Object is not in a state to be updated.")
  }

  def beforeDelete() {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Object is not in a state to be deleted.")
  }
  ```
- Haven't tried `mapWith` for inserts / updates as it actually don't allow creation of a table but everything like a domain is available.

  ```
   static mapWith = "none"
  ```
- Last but not least we could also use transactions but these won't be of that much help. Like in service you could use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`. But this will just help in services.
- Also, you could disable versioning and want cache just only for reads.

  ```
  static mapping = { 
    cache usage: 'read-only' 
    version false 
  }
  ```

I found [this topic about read-only domain](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Read-only-domain-td1461440.html) very helpful and worth.

I'm not sure about third bullet but you could try this as well.

Hope It would help!